Voltage and current on two identical TVS diodes in parallel during a voltage spike
Suppose I have two identical unidirectional TVS diodes (A and B) connected in parallel to a voltage source and suddenly a voltage spike occurs (spike voltage > voltage clamp of the TVS diode specs and current peak < Ippm of the TVS diode specs).
What happens to the current on both devices:

Current will be distributed among A and B equally?
Current will pass through A or B only?
Final voltage clamp is calculated as if there were only one TVS diode?


You may find the paralleling comments here relevant: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/680039/do-mosfets-share-avalanche-energy/680051#680051 I seem to also recall writing in regards to TVS specifically but I don't see it offhand.

It might be worth disambiguating one thing: are the diodes identical as in equal V(I) curves? Or "identical" in the sense of same part number (individual characteristics vary)?

I refer identical in the context of the same part number

may i know the reason for downvote??

There is no such thing as identical diodes in real life.

With 2 identical TVS diodes, surge current will be shared equally and, the clamping voltage will be dictated by the current flowing through either of the 2 devices (it will be somewhat less than the clamping voltage if only one TVS diode took the full surge current).

could you explain me why if current is shared equal among them and considering both have same Rd, why clamping voltage is not equal also?

The two identical diodes will have identical voltages across them and identical currents through them.  The spec sheet lists a clamping voltage at a certain current for each diode, but since there are 2 diodes the listed clamping voltage will happen when the specified current through ONE of the diodes reaches the specified value.  The voltage across the 2 diodes will be less than it would be for a single diode when the total current is the datasheet clamping current.  It's not that the clamping voltages are different between the two diodes.

Assuming the diodes are at the same temperature.  If one is mounted on a hot spot for example, then the currents will be different.  But I imagine the question wasn't considering temperature differences.

@marcosbc ohm's law and parallel resistors vs a single resistor carrying the full current
